# referencing a global Dict from class methods Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary on another python script that i run(load?) first, i would like methods inside the strat class to reference keys/values inside this dictionary in a "settings" script, but whenever i try to reference it, i get a nameerror "pair_config" not defined
please excuse the agricultural coding.

```
 pair_config = {
     'AUD_JPY' : {
         'Starthour' : ('0600')
                }
                }





class Strat:
    def __init__(self, pair, granularity = zgranularity, mult = zmult):
        self.pair = pair
        self.granulatrity = granularity
        self.mult = mult

     def candle_since(self):
         global pair_config
         xx = 0
         toopen = str(self.pair+zgranularity)
         with open(toopen+'.csv', 'r') as f:
             reader = csv.reader(f)
             for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                 for j, column in enumerate(row):
                     if str(pair_config[self.pair]['Starthour']) in column:
                         print('candles since open ' ,i)
                         xx = xx+1
                         return i
                         if xx == 1:
                             break
```

Comment: You might want to include the Strat class within the other script that defines the variables you're trying to access.  If you don't want to do that, you should try and navigate to where these variables should exist.  If you can't find them that means you're not storing them.  Then re-visit script 1.

Comment: Thanks, i've moved the settings to a whole new script setts.py to avoid circular imports, and have now "navigated" to the variables by using setts.pair_config[self.pair]['Starthour'])